# aws configure delete access key profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I seem to be having difficulty deleting the access key profile i created for a test user using

```
aws configure --profile testuser
```

I have tried deleting the entries in my `~/.aws`directory however when i run `aws configure`, i am getting the following error.

`botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (testuser) could not be found`

A workaround is adding `[profile testuser]` in my `~/.aws/config` file but i dont want to do that. I want to remove all traces of this testuser profile from my machine.

Answer (score 7):

The [Configuring the AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html) documentation page lists various places where configuration files are stored, such as:

- Linux: `~/.aws/credentials`
- Windows: `C:\Users\USERNAME \.aws\credentials`

There is also a **default profile**, which sounds like something that might be causing your situation:

- Linux: `export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=user2`
- Windows: `set AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=user2`

I suggest checking to see whether that **environment variable** has been set.

Comment: Thank you very much. I ran `unset AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` which ended up solving the problem.

Comment: Hi @jebjeb if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

look for a hidden folder; .aws/credentials
it path name is most likely: '/Users/COMPUTER_NAME/.aws/credentials'
change computer name to your computer name, there you will find two files,
config and credentials, edit them with a regular text editor